# Delete a specific row TO DATATABLE using jsf and mysql

Tags: mysql, jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces, datatable

I'm trying for four days to pass a value from my (xadmin.xhtml) to my (JadminBeans.java) but no luck so far. what i want to do is when i push the delete button inside a row using datatable all the data inside that row should be deleted form my datatable and mysql database. so this is a part of my code :
P.s: i'm new to java EE and jsf

**xadmin.xhtml**

```
<h:dataTable value="#{Jadmin.messages}" var="o"
            styleClass="order-table"
            headerClass="order-table-header"
            rowClasses="order-table-odd-row,order-table-even-row"
        >

        <h:column>

            <f:facet name="header">username</f:facet>
            #{o.username}

        </h:column>

        <h:column>

            <f:facet name="header">password</f:facet>
            #{o.password}

        </h:column>

        <h:column>

            <f:facet name="header">permission</f:facet>
            #{o.permission}

        </h:column>


        <h:column>

            <f:facet name="header">delete</f:facet>

            <h:commandLink value="Delete" action="#{Jadmin.delete(o.username)}" />

        </h:column>

        </h:dataTable>
```

**JadminBeans.java**

```
@ManagedBean(name = "Jadmin")
@SessionScoped
public class JadminBeans {

    private String username, password, permission;
    private JadminController JaC;

    // insert getter setter here
    public List<JadminBeans> getMessages() {
        return JadminDAO.getAllUsers();
    }
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public String getPermission() {
        return permission;
    }
    public void setPermission(String permission) {
        this.permission = permission;
    }


  public void  delete(String usr) {

     System.out.println("JadminBeans >> delete() ---------- username= "+usr);
      JadminDAO.deleteUser(usr);

    }

}
```

**JadminDAO.java**

```
 public static List<JadminBeans> getAllUsers() {
        List<JadminBeans> users = new ArrayList<JadminBeans>();
        try {
            Connection con = DBconnection.getConnection();
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select * from users");
            while (rs.next()) {
                JadminBeans user = new JadminBeans();
                 user.setUsername(rs.getString("username"));
                 user.setPassword(rs.getString("password"));
                 user.setPermission(rs.getString("permission"));

                 System.out.println("JadminDAO > getAllUsers(): "+rs.getString("username"));

                users.add(user);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return users;
    }
public static void deleteUser(String id) {
        try {
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("delete from users where username=?");
            // Parameters start with 1
            preparedStatement.setString(1, id);
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("JadminDAO >> deleteUser ----------"+ id);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("JadminDAO >> deleteUser----------- SQLException :(");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is the problem that `usr` is empty in `delete()` method, or that it's not deleted from the database? Explain a little how does it not work, any exceptions?

Comment: hi @PredragMaric the problem is that usr is empty. that means my xhtml file pass an empty value to my java file

Comment: Try changing `action="#{Jadmin.delete(o.username)}"` to `actionListener="#{Jadmin.delete(o.username)}"`, or return String from `delete()` instead of void (`action` attribute should resolve to a string).

Comment: I did what you told me by using actionListener="#{Jadmin.delete(o.username)}" and i got this error (Method not found: class admin_page.JadminBeans.delete(java.lang.String))

Comment: for the second suggestion doesn't work at all but thanks @PredragMaric :)

Comment: Are you sure that `public void delete(String usr)` is there in `JadminBeans` class, when you try with `actionListener`? The exception explicitly says that you don't have a method with that signature.

Answer (score 0):

- userBean:

  ```
  public void deleteUser(String  user){
     UserDAO.DeleteUser(user);
  }
  ```
- xhtml file:

  ```
  <p:commandButton id="confirm" value="Yes Sure"
                  oncomplete="confirmation.hide()"
                  actionListener="#{userBean.deleteUser(userBean.selectedUser.user)}"
                  update=":form1:overviewTableUser">
  </p:commandButton>
  ```
- UserDAO :

  ```
  public static void DeleteUser(String user) {
      Connection con = null;
      PreparedStatement ps = null;

      try {
          con = Database.getConnection();
           String sql="delete  from userinfo where user=?";
         ps= con.prepareStatement(sql); 
          // Parameters start with 1
          ps.setString(1,"user");

          ps.executeUpdate();

          System.out.println("user deleted successfully");


      } catch (SQLException e) {
          System.out.println(" SQLException :(");
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
  ```

This is the way that i fix this problem ;)